# Android/Xamarin/Telerik memory problems with ObservableCollection

Tags: android, xamarin, telerik

I have a list view that needs to be updated (unlike all the example code out there that use static lists). The xaml/code snippet looks like:

```
<telerikDataControls:RadListView x:Name="processesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    Grid.Row="2">

class ActionProcessItemViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase { 
// etc.
}

class ActionProcessesViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    ObservableCollection<ActionProcessItemViewModel> _items = new ObservableCollection<ActionProcessItemViewModel>();

    internal ActionProcessesViewModel()
    {
    }

    internal ObservableCollection<ActionProcessItemViewModel> Items => _items;

    // this is an update not a replace: incoming list may be a partial snapshot
    internal void UpdateItems(List<ActionProcessItemViewModel> updatedItems)
    {
        // remove any about-to-be-replaced items
        foreach (ActionProcessItemViewModel it in updatedItems)
        {
            var itemsRows = _items.Where(row => row.ActionProcess.Id == it.ActionProcess.Id);
            if (itemsRows.Count() == 1)
               _items.Remove(itemsRows.First());
        }

        foreach (ActionProcessItemViewModel it in updatedItems)
            _items.Add(it);

        var sorted = Sort(_items.ToList());
        _items.Clear(); // replace 'items' with the sorted list

        foreach (ActionProcessItemViewModel ap in sorted)
            _items.Add(ap);

        OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }

    private List<ActionProcessItemViewModel> Sort(List<ActionProcessItemViewModel> items)
    {
        return items
             .OrderByDescending(o => o.CurrentState?.Time.Ticks).ToList()
             .OrderByDescending(o => o.CurrentState?.Severity).ToList()
             .OrderBy(o => o.CurrentState?.Type).ToList()
             ;
    }
```

I know that updating _items causes a memory leak. I think. Garbage collection, or the lack of garbage collection, makes it very hard to know what is a leak and what isn't. I have used the Xamarin Profiler which confirms lots of allocations of Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.BindablePropertyContext. 
Been looking through Xamarin/Telerik/ObservableCollection docs and stuff, but can't find anything that says I am supposed to do something special here. How do I fix the memory leak?

[I have tried various things to see the affect; like skipping the sort, which didn't help. I also tried not updating the list at all, that helps a lot (this isn't the only memory leak, just the worst of them). ]

Comment: One thing I thought to try, update to the latest Xamarin Forms using nuget. The result? Visual Studio Professional could no longer open the project (VS would hang). Great.

So I went back to the older version of Xamarin, and still VS hangs. Next, install VS Enterprise, open project, wait, close project. Now VS professional works again. The stuff programmers have to put up with, omg.

Comment: The call to _items.Remove(itemsRows.First()); seems to be the problem, so I am trying to replace it by updating the underlying data structures; but now the data on the screen never changes, even though I am calling OnPropertyChanged("Items");

Comment: Added OnPropertyChanged calls to the individual ActionProcessItemViewModel objects and seems to be working